# WSO2 Identitiy Server Password change, getting issue “Can not access the directory service for user”

Tags: soap, ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am attempting a password reset feature in wso2 identity server where I'm using LDAP as secondary storage.

I'm using this( https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Users#ConfiguringUsers-UpdateuserusingSOAP) link as documentation to update user details by calling https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl admin service.
I'm using LDAP as secondary storage. but, when I'm trying to update the password by the updateCredential() method getting the below issue

getting this error response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Can not access the directory service for user : yellow@xyz.com</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

where I'm sending this request to updateCredential() method

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:updateCredential>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:userName>USERS/yellow@xyz.com</ser:userName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:newCredential>123456</ser:newCredential>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:oldCredential>123456789</ser:oldCredential>
      </ser:updateCredential>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Would you able to change the password through the management console. Is this error observed in only in the SOAP request

Comment: yes, I am able to change the password perfectly from management console.
this issue I am only getting in SOAP response when i'm sending the service request.

Comment: Do you see any errors in wso2carbon.log when this issue happens ?

Comment: How did you authenticate the soap service? Is it basic auth? If so, check whether that user has required privileges.